# How to open app when notification received (React Native&Onesignal)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webrtc, onesignal

I am developing messenger with webrtc calls using react-native and onesignal.

Currently, when there is an incoming call, app receives notification and user must click on notification to open answer screen. This is very inconvenient, i want to make the answer screen open automatically when phone received notification, like as Whatsapp or Viber.

I already tried put something like `this.props.navigation.navigate('CallPage')` to `onReceive(notification)` handler, but it works only if app is on foreground.

If it's possible to make this using react-native, please give advice

Comment: His question about navigate to desired screen on click, my question about open app when received.

Comment: Answer is the same for both questions. The OP on the other question refers clicking on a notification and opening up the app.

Comment: It sounds good, i will try to use Linking for opening answer screen without any clicks

Comment: @user3257662 Did linking work? I want to do the same thing(without clicking) and I'm stuck.